# Error: Internal or external type is not allowed for public or external functions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

This is the function. I am very new to this. Can someone please tell me what is wrong in this.

```
function getData(string Key) constant returns (string[], string[]) {

    uint length = data.length;

    string[] memory key = new string[](length);
    string[] memory hash = new string[](length);

    for(uint i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        Data memory currentData;
        currentData = data[i];

        key[i] = currentData.key;
        hash[i] = currentData.hash;
    }

    return (key,hash);
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete code? What's data in this function is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining about `returns(string[])`.

You're trying to return variable length arrays but the interface is limited to 16 fixed length arguments or 8 strings, with a further caveat about strings - they can't be passed between contracts.

These are limitations of the current compiler.

This code replicates the same error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract TestContract{

    function test() constant returns(string[], string[]) {
        // ^ no good
    }

}
```

If you need a workaround for large arrays, you can call return vals by row number. Something like:

```
function x(uint row) constant returns(string) {
  return myString[row][
}
```

Or even:

```
string[] public myString;
```

By declaring it `public`, you get a "free" getter function that does the same thing. For completeness, I should say that `public` has additional implications if any contracts inherit the code.

Hope it helps.